# Find ip address of the server from the docker container running inside this server

Tags: docker, ip

I have a server and inside this server a docker container is running, I have a shell script inside the container which needs the ip of the server not the ip of the docker container. Is there any way to get that ?

I googled for long time and I wasn't able to find a similar question.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the iproute2 package and use the `ip` command to show the default route like this

```
ip route show default
```

To just get the IP address, you can do

```
ip route show default | awk '{print $3}'
```

To get it into a variable in a script, do

```
HOSTIP=$(ip route show default | awk '{print $3}')
```

Comment: This command gives the ip of the docker container, but I need the ip address of the server on which the docker container is running

Comment: It gives the address of the host as seen from the container, i.e. the host's address on the bridge network. I don't know how (or if) you can get the host's address on a different network than the bridge network.